# I am not able to apply background image to div class back

Tags: php, html, css

I am unable to put the background image for div class back and even couldn't reduce the gap between log in and the line.I have set all of them 0px (border,padding margin).I couldn't find solutions and are there any editors which show CSS errors?

```
<?php
 //   session_start();
function redirect_to($new_location){
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
}
$email="";
$password="";
$passwd_err=array();
$email_err=array();
$passwd_err[0]=$email_err[0]="";
session_start();
$_SESSION['custno']="";
function db_connect(){
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='manoj';
    $dbpass='harsha';
    $dbname='vintage';
    $connection=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("connection failed");
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    else{
        return $connection;
    }
}

    function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
        // existing hash contains format and salt at start
      $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
      if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
function email_validation($emai)
{
    if (filter_var($emai, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $email_err[0]="INVALID EMAIL";
        return false;
    }

}
function password_validations($passwd)
{
    $regex="$\S*(?=\S{8,30})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$";
    if(preg_match_all($regex,$passwd))
    {
       $passwd_err[0]="";
      return true;
    }
    else{
            $passwd_err[0]="Invalid Password";
      return false;
    }
      /*
    Explaining $\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$
    $ = beginning of string
    \S* = any set of characters
    (?=\S{8,}) = of at least length 8
    (?=\S*[a-z]) = containing at least one lowercase letter
    (?=\S*[A-Z]) = and at least one uppercase letter
    (?=\S*[\d]) = and at least one number
    (?=\S*[\W]) = and at least a special character (non-word characters)
    $ = end of the string

 */


}

    if(isset($_POST["Dive_In"]))
    {
        $connect=db_connect();
            if($_POST["password"]==""){
                $passwd_err[0]="Cannot be left blank";
            }
            if(($_POST["username"]==""))
            {
                $email_err[0]="cannot be left blank";
            }
            if( ($_POST["password"]!="") &&($_POST["username"]!="") )
            {
                $email=$_POST["username"];
                $password=$_POST["password"];
                if(email_validation($email)){
                    $email_sql="select CustNo from Customer where email='{$email}' ";
                    $query=mysqli_query($connect,$email_sql);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1)
                    {
                        $result=mysqli_fetch_row($query);
                        $CustNo=$result[0];
                        if(password_validations($password))
                        {
                            $password_sql="select password from passwd s where s.em_id = $CustNo ";
                            $passwd_sql=mysqli_query($connect,$password_sql);
                            $pass_sql=mysqli_fetch_row($passwd_sql);
                            if(password_check($password,$pass_sql[0]))
                            {
                              $_SESSION['custno']=$CustNo;
                              mysqli_close($connect);
                              redirect_to("login.php");
                            }
                            else{

                                $passwd_err[0]="Wrong Password";
                                mysqli_close($connect);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $passwd_err[0]="Invalid Password";
                            mysqli_close($connect);
                        }


                    }
                    else{
                        $email_err[0]="User does not exist";
                    }
                }
                else{
                        $email_err[0]="Invalid email";
                        mysqli_close($connect);
                    }
               /*if(password_validations($password))
                {
                    echo "true";
                }
                else{
                 echo "false";
                }*/

            }
    }
    else{
         $email="";
        $password="";
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
    p,div,h1,h2,h3,ul,li,form,span{

        margin: 0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .back{
        background-size:cover;
        background-image:url("/img/angry.jpg");
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .header{
        background-color: #F3F5F6;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 0px;

    }
    div.signin{
        background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.62);
            border:1px solid silver;
            width:350px;
            height:361px;
            border-radius:4px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-right:20px;
        float: right;
    }
    .text{
        width: 275px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius:6px;
        margin-bottom:18px;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
    }
        .bod{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
    font-size: 20px;

        }
    .box{
        margin-top:80px;
        margin-left:30px;
       }
       ul{
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left:35px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space:nowrap; <!-- ensures that text stays on one line.-->
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    float: right;
       }
       ul li{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
    font-size: 16px;

       }
       li a{
    color:#0084CB;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
       }


    </style>
</head>

<body class="bod">
    <div class="header">
    <img style="margin-left:15px;margin-right: 5px;margin-top: 10px; position:absolute;" src="/img/download.jpeg" height='50' width='50'align="center" >
    <p style="color:#0084CB;font-size: 30px; float:left; position:relative; margin-top: 17px; margin-left: 70px;">
         Vintage Bank
    </p>
    <ul >
    <li>
      <a href="index.php"><p>HOME</p></a>
    </li>
    <li  >
    <a href="admins/Employee/em_admin.php">EMPLOY</a>
    </li>
    <li >
    <a href="admins/Manager/admin_mgr.php">MANAGER</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="back">
    <div class="signin">
    <div style="color:white;font-family: 'Arial';margin-top:22px;margin-left: 15px; font-size: 25px;">LOGIN</div>
    <div style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:10px;color: white;">____________________________</div>
        <form name="login" action="index.php" method="post" class="box">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" size="40px;" value="" ><?php echo $email_err[0]; ?></br>
            <input type="password" class="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="40px;" value="" ><?php echo $passwd_err[0]; ?></br>
            <input type="submit" name="Dive_In"  va_delue="Dive In">
        </form>

    </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you check you background image url path ?

Comment: yes i hav cheked it is inside img folder

Comment: you can try online css validator site like this http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
    <?php
 //   session_start();
function redirect_to($new_location){
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
}
$email="";
$password="";
$passwd_err=array();
$email_err=array();
$passwd_err[0]=$email_err[0]="";
session_start();
$_SESSION['custno']="";
function db_connect(){
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='manoj';
    $dbpass='harsha';
    $dbname='vintage';
    $connection=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("connection failed");
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    else{
        return $connection;
    }
}

    function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
        // existing hash contains format and salt at start
      $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
      if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
function email_validation($emai)
{
    if (filter_var($emai, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $email_err[0]="INVALID EMAIL";
        return false;
    }

}
function password_validations($passwd)
{
    $regex="$\S*(?=\S{8,30})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$";
    if(preg_match_all($regex,$passwd))
    {
       $passwd_err[0]="";
      return true;
    }
    else{
            $passwd_err[0]="Invalid Password";
      return false;
    }
      /*
    Explaining $\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$
    $ = beginning of string
    \S* = any set of characters
    (?=\S{8,}) = of at least length 8
    (?=\S*[a-z]) = containing at least one lowercase letter
    (?=\S*[A-Z]) = and at least one uppercase letter
    (?=\S*[\d]) = and at least one number
    (?=\S*[\W]) = and at least a special character (non-word characters)
    $ = end of the string

 */


}

    if(isset($_POST["Dive_In"]))
    {
        $connect=db_connect();
            if($_POST["password"]==""){
                $passwd_err[0]="Cannot be left blank";
            }
            if(($_POST["username"]==""))
            {
                $email_err[0]="cannot be left blank";
            }
            if( ($_POST["password"]!="") &&($_POST["username"]!="") )
            {
                $email=$_POST["username"];
                $password=$_POST["password"];
                if(email_validation($email)){
                    $email_sql="select CustNo from Customer where email='{$email}' ";
                    $query=mysqli_query($connect,$email_sql);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1)
                    {
                        $result=mysqli_fetch_row($query);
                        $CustNo=$result[0];
                        if(password_validations($password))
                        {
                            $password_sql="select password from passwd s where s.em_id = $CustNo ";
                            $passwd_sql=mysqli_query($connect,$password_sql);
                            $pass_sql=mysqli_fetch_row($passwd_sql);
                            if(password_check($password,$pass_sql[0]))
                            {
                              $_SESSION['custno']=$CustNo;
                              mysqli_close($connect);
                              redirect_to("login.php");
                            }
                            else{

                                $passwd_err[0]="Wrong Password";
                                mysqli_close($connect);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $passwd_err[0]="Invalid Password";
                            mysqli_close($connect);
                        }


                    }
                    else{
                        $email_err[0]="User does not exist";
                    }
                }
                else{
                        $email_err[0]="Invalid email";
                        mysqli_close($connect);
                    }
               /*if(password_validations($password))
                {
                    echo "true";
                }
                else{
                 echo "false";
                }*/

            }
    }
    else{
         $email="";
        $password="";
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
    p,div,h1,h2,h3,ul,li,form,span{

        margin: 0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .back{
        background-size:cover;
        background-image:url("/img/angry.jpg");
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .header{
        background-color: #F3F5F6;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 0px;

    }
    div.signin{
        background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.62);
            border:1px solid silver;
            width:350px;
            height:361px;
            border-radius:4px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-right:20px;
        float: right;
    }
    .text{
        width: 275px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius:6px;
        margin-bottom:18px;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
    }
        .bod{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
    font-size: 20px;

        }
    .box{
        margin-top:80px;
        margin-left:30px;
       }
       ul{
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left:35px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space:nowrap; <!-- ensures that text stays on one line.-->
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    float: right;
       }
       ul li{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
    font-size: 16px;

       }
       li a{
    color:#0084CB;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
       }


    </style>
</head>

<body class="bod">
    <div class="header">
    <img style="margin-left:15px;margin-right: 5px;margin-top: 10px; position:absolute;" src="/img/download.jpeg" height='50' width='50'align="center" >
    <p style="color:#0084CB;font-size: 30px; float:left; position:relative; margin-top: 17px; margin-left: 70px;">
         Vintage Bank
    </p>
    <ul >
    <li>
      <a href="index.php"><p>HOME</p></a>
    </li>
    <li  >
    <a href="admins/Employee/em_admin.php">EMPLOY</a>
    </li>
    <li >
    <a href="admins/Manager/admin_mgr.php">MANAGER</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="back">
    <div class="signin">
    <div style="color:white;font-family: 'Arial';margin-top:22px;margin-left: 15px; font-size: 25px;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;">LOGIN</div>
        <form name="login" action="index.php" method="post" class="box">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" size="40px;" value="" ><?php echo $email_err[0]; ?></br>
            <input type="password" class="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="40px;" value="" ><?php echo $passwd_err[0]; ?></br>
            <input type="submit" name="Dive_In"  va_delue="Dive In">
        </form>

    </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have given border-bottom on
 <div style="color:white;font-family: 'Arial';margin-top:22px;margin-left: 15px; font-size: 25px;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;">LOGIN</div> and removed ______ div. Is it working?

Comment: yeah thanks for  the line haven't thought of it but the image is still not getting applied to back class

Answer (score 0):

Try this

    .back
    {
        background-size:cover;

```
    background:url("/img/angry.jpg");
    width:361PX;
    height:350PX;

 }
.header{
    background-color: #F3F5F6;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border: 0px;

}
div.signin{
    background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.62);
        border:1px solid silver;
        width:350px;
        height:361px;
        border-radius:4px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float: right;
}
.text{
    width: 275px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin-bottom:18px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
}
    .bod{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
font-size: 20px;

    }
.box{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:30px;
   }
   ul{
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left:35px;
padding:0px;
white-space:nowrap; <!-- ensures that text stays on one line.-->
list-style: none;
padding:0px;
float: right;
   }
   ul li{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
font-size: 16px;

   }
   li a{
color:#0084CB;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
   }


</style>
```